# cordova push notification don't trigger notification event when app is launched directly

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I am experimenting with the push notification plugin for cordova and it is mostly working as expected.
I can send notifications to my android and ios devices and they also arrive there. But only when the app is already running on screen or lauched via the notification itself the `push.on('notification',function(data){alert(data);})` is triggered. When I lauch the (not running) app after recieving the notification directly via the drawer, the notification event is not triggered.
This occurs on android as well as ios, hence I suspect some kind of configuration problem.

My plugin is initialized after the `deviceready` event has fired with:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        senderID: "MY_SENDER_ID"
    },
    browser: {
        pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
    },
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true"
    },
    windows: {}
});
```

Or is this expected behavior?